# Make API where other sides can ajax submit to our server

Tags: rest

We have a set with campaign sites ala http://safeinthecity.com. We want to make an as generic API as possible where other third party sites can integrate the form (the one in the rectangular on the right side), and the form should be posted with Ajax to our server.

And here the problem arrise - cause of the cross domain restriction the browsers has implemented its not possible. We could make third parties post the form in normal way to our server, but then the user will be redirected from the third party site to our site, and that's not easy to sell in. One solution would be the third parties to add a server script (PHP, Java, .NET, Ruby on Rails, what ever) which they post to, and then the third party server script makes the request through a API equivalent to Apache HTTP client), but that is very very cumbersome and hard to sell in. Is there a smarter way to solve this issue which I haven't spotted yet?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured out a way, even thus I dislike the non-support for POST, PUT, DELETE

http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/